# How to fetch actual pivottable data from first rowfield of it using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Thanks for all your help in past. I got stuck again in something and I am not able to solve it after so many tries and once again need your help.

I want to extract values of the 1st rowfield which are showing in the pivottable after applying all the filters. Below code is providing ALL the value of 1st rowfield even though only 5 values are showing in the pivottable.

Check the screen shot here:

[image]

As per image above, I want only 7,41,60,61,62 values however loop is running for all the 80 SN.NO of the sourcedata.

```
Sub GetRowItems()

    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim val As String

    'Set variables
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Activate
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set pf = pt.RowFields(1)

    'pt.PivotFields(pf.Name).DataRange.Select
    If pf Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For j = 1 To pf.PivotItems.count
        'MsgBox pf.PivotItems(j).Name
        val = pf.PivotItems(j).Name
    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GetRowItems()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Activate

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set pf = pt.TableRange1.Columns(1)

If pf Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
pf.Select

    For Each cell In Selection.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, 1))
    'Because you have Grand Totals for rows <Selection.Rows.Count - 1>
    'Else <Selection.Rows.Count>
    Debug.Print cell
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mohit .. If this answers your question, please upvote/accept the answer to close the question

Comment: Neither I am able to upvote or seeing any option to accept the answer..  I clicked on triangle button and got msg - Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.